# Cronntab hourly and specific hour

Tags: linux, cron

how to cron tab program hourly and specific time ex?

For example:

`at 3,6,9,12,15,18,21 o'clock and at 23.55` ?

Thanks!

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking here. Could you [edit] the post to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.

The only way is to specify "55" minute and all hours:

```
55 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,23 * * *
```

Or you can create 2 different cron jobs:

- First will run every "3,6,9,12,15,18,21" hours:

  ```
  0 3,6,9,12,15,18,21,23 * * *
  ```
- Second job will run at 23:55:

  ```
  55 23 * * *
  ```